# Webservices: Should returning or passing enums be avoided?

Tags: .net, web-services, enums

I have a .net webservice that services data updates to client applications. As part of the mechanism, we used an enum to differentiate between 'types' of updates. So the webmethod returns a list of types that have an enum to define what the update is for.

We recently added an additional 'update type' to the system. While this worked fine for the new version of our client application (also in .net), older versions threw errors as the new enum type (which is serialized as a string and passed down the wire) could not be cast to the enum (as the enum value isn't specified in the generated code in Reference.cs).

Our answer is to avoid including that new value in the webmethod's result (to satisfy the older versions of the client app) and use a new method for here on that instead passes the INT value of the enum to client applications.

In terms of backward compatibility and robustness, is it a good idea to even pass Enum values when dealing with webservices? We just had a new value to account for, but I'm thinking in terms of refactoring/renaming enums for the future.

Defining the rule "Don't pass enum values over webmethods. Pass their INT values instead" seems like a really broad rule so I'm not certain of the unintended consequences when supporting older versions of client applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is nothing wrong with passing an `enum` around. When the result is serialized as XML using XSD there is even a specific element to define enums (`xs:enumeration`).

I had like to see the actual problems with the older client software to have a better idea of the problem, but when talking standards, this should work.

Comment: To illustrate the problem with the older clients: Enum 'updateType' had the values 'AUpdate','BUpdate','CUpdate'. Now the same webMethod returns 'DUpdate'. Older client receives the data but is unable to deserialize 'DUpdate' into it's enum "UpdateType" because it's not defined - "Instance validation error: 'DUpdate' is not a valid value for UpdateType."
So the enum is being serialized correctly; its the older client not able to understand the serializied enum.

Comment: @MoSlo: Okay, that is a valid point. But how would you circumvent this in any other solution? It is still an unexpected result.

Comment: indeed it is. The idea prevent this is to instead pass the INT of the enum and cast that INT value to a client-side enum. That way, any INT value that's unexpected can be safely ignored (as opposed to current scenario: deserializing result = kaboom). This scenario has made us consider other scenarios, as in "by the way, we can't rename the enums or else older clients break". So the crux is: "apply standard - no passing enums in webmethods for backwards compatibility. their int values only." Good idea or problem we're not seeing?

Comment: @MoSlow: In my opinion, client and server versions should always match. So in real life, with a new release, I would create a new service. When support for older versions are gone, remove the old service. In that way, you will never hit compatibility problems.

Comment: Yup, that sounds best. Especially when dealing with large scale changes between one service and the next.
In this specific instance we're going to add another webmethod for backwards compatibility but with future work the full service idea is more robust and better accepting of changes. Thanks!